# Remove a type modifier from schema with a migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

Let's pretend that my schema looks like this:

```
create_table "bunnies", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
end
```

How do I write a migration that removes the "null: false" constraint on my schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
change_column :bunnies, :created_at, :datetime, null: true
```

Comment: Nice, didn't realize it would be that easy. I was worried it'd leave the null type modifier up there. As a follow up, how would one remove a default type modifier for text? For example    `default: ""`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. `change_column :bunnies, :content, :text, default: nil`